# Как сделать div элемент зоной для загрузки файлов

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Вопрос явно глупый, но я не могу найти рабочего варианта четвертый час.
Мне нужно, чтобы фотографии можно было перетягивать на элементы типа `image`, которые представляют собой папку. Никакие обёртки типа `form` `input` не использую.

Надеялся найти какие-нибудь атрибуты позволящие взаимодействовать с `drag-n-drop`, но ничего подобного, похоже, нет.

Единственное, что нашёл: установка события `ondrop`

> **Define the drop zone:**
> The target element of the drop event needs an ondrop global event handler. The following code snippet shows how this is done with a  element:

— не сработало.

```
block.ondrop = function (){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Сброшено!"); // Не запускается
}
```

Другое событие `dragenter`срабатывает нормально.

```
block.ondragenter = () => onDragenEnter();
```

Следующий код также не даёт возможности перетаскивать файлы в нужную область:

```
funcion onDragenEnter(){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", e.target.id);
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
}
```

В общем. Как я могу реализовать функцию `drop` внутрь обычного элемента? (не используя вышеупомянутые `imput`, `form` и другие)
Желаемый результат был достигнут [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/9C2EF/), однако всё-ещё не работает у меня

Comment: А эмдиэн почитать? _"If the mouse is released over an element that is a valid drop target, that is, one that cancelled the last `dragenter` or `dragover` event, then the drop will be successful, and a `drop` event will fire at the target. Otherwise, the drag operation is cancelled, and no `drop` event is fired."_. Если и по написанному не получается, то нужно добавить в вопрос [repro].

Comment: `funcion onDragenEnter() { e.preventDefault(); /*...*/ }` — синтаксическая ошибка + `e` undefined. Оно по определению не сможет работать. И обрати свое внимание на последнее предложение предыдущего комментария.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы Ивент `ondrop` сработал обязательно требуются ивенты `dragenter` и `dragover` с event.preventDefault и event.stopPropogation()

Я все-ещё не понимаю, как именно это работает, однако спасибо комментарию от @yar85, он помог.